# Get Selected Field off a value on a ComboBox bound to ObservableDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, observablecollection, model-binding

This is embarrassing.

I am trying to bind an ObservableDictionary to a ComboBox.

I have done this OK, but I am further bind the selected value to a property but I am not getting the correct value of the field.

This is my Model

```
public class Category
{
    public Int64 CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryRef { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is My ViewModel:

```
public Dictionary<string, Category> _categoryFields;

public Dictionary<string, Category> CategoryFields
{
    get => _categoryFields;
    set
    {
        _categoryFields = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CategoryFields");
    }
}

private string _categorySelected;

public string CategorySelected
{
    get => _categorySelected;
    set
    {
        _categorySelected= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CategorySelected");
        EvJobCategoryHasChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This my View:

```
<ComboBoxAdv 
    DisplayMemberPath="Value.Description"                                         
    SelectedValue="{Binding CategorySelected,Mode=TwoWay}"                                         
    SelectedValuePath="{Binding Value.Description}"                                        
    ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryFields}" />
```

I am trying to get the Description Selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely your problem:

```
SelectedValuePath="{Binding Value.Description}"
```

This property does not need to be bound; it should be a property path, just like `DisplayMemberPath`.  Change it to:

```
SelectedValuePath="Value.Description"
```